# Matlab - convert sparse matrix to complex-sparse matrix

Tags: matlab

I have sparse matrix `A` which I need to convert to complex-sparse matrix by setting its imaginary part to zero.

```
A = sprand(3,3,0.5);
A_c = complex(A,0);
```

However, this throws me an error that A should be full.

> Error using complex
>
> Real input A must be numeric, real, and full.

Is there any work-around to achieve this?

Comment: The inefficient way of doing this is of course `A_c = sparse(complex(full(A)));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I first answered this question I did not consider the way complex sparse matrices are implemented in MATLAB. I tricked myself into the following answer.

#### Naive solution

You could apply `complex()` to each element of the matrix.

```
A_c = spfun(@(x)complex(x,0),A)
```

Here `@(x)complex(x,0)` denotes an anonymous function that applied to each element `x` of the matrix `A` returns a complex number with `Re=x` and `Im=0`. And `spfun` just returns a new sparse matrix produced by applying our anonymous function to the nonzero elements of the matrix `A`.

What happens is that this solution returns an object identical to the original matrix. The matrix `A_c` occupies the same number of bytes and is equal to the original matrix `A`.

```
>> whos A A_c
Variables in the current scope:

   Attr Name        Size                     Bytes  Class
   ==== ====        ====                     =====  =====
        A           3x3                         76  double
        A_c         3x3                         76  double
```

A comment from [Florian Roemer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7405355/florian) made me reconsider my answer.

#### Explanation

The representation of sparse matrices in MATLAB is described in a [paper by Gilbert, Moler and Schreiber](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/otherdocs/simax.pdf) published in 1991.

A real matrix is represented as a single vector of nonzero elements of the corresponding storage class (i.e. double or complex) stored in column-wise order plus an integer vector of indices of these elements in their respective columns plus an integer vector of indices of locations where new columns start. I.e. an `m*n` sparse matrix with `k` nonzero elements would occupy n*4 + k*12 bytes with 4 bytes for integers and 8 bytes to store reals as double precision. That is a 3x3 real sparse matrix with 5 nonzero entries occupies (4+5)*4+8*5 = 76 bytes.

A complex sparse matrix would have another real array for the imaginary parts of all nonzero entries of the matrix but only if *at least one element* has a nonzero imaginary part.

Consider

```
>> B = sprand(3,3,0.5)
B =    
Compressed Column Sparse (rows = 3, cols = 3, nnz = 5 [56%])    
  (1, 1) ->  0.46883
  ....
>> B_c = B ; B_c(1,1) += 1e-100i
B_c =
Compressed Column Sparse (rows = 3, cols = 3, nnz = 5 [56%])
   (1, 1) ->  4.6883e-01 + 1.0000e-100i
    ....
```

Now we have made MATLAB to allocate additional storage for the imaginary parts of each nonzero entry of the original matrix, even though only one of the entries has a nonzero imaginary part.

```
>> whos B B_c
Variables in the current scope:

   Attr Name        Size                     Bytes  Class
   ==== ====        ====                     =====  =====
        B           3x3                         76  double
   c    B_c         3x3                        116  double
```

Now `B_c` is a proper complex sparse matrix that occupies

```
   (4+5)*4 + 8 * 5 + 8 * 5 = 116 bytes
```

#### Conclusion

If you just need a sparse matrix with zero imaginary parts, then do nothing to the original matrix.

If you need a matrix that actually allocates storage for the complex entries and carries the `complex` attribute, then add a small imaginary value to at least one of the nonzero entries of the original matrix.

**Matlab remark:** I did not test this in actual Matlab but Octave is quite happy with this solution.

Comment: It looks really correct but somehow, the zero imaginary part gets truncated, and A_c remains "double" instead of "double, complex" (tested in R2014a and R2016b). That said, `A_c = spfun(@(x)complex(x,eps),A)` works fine.

Comment: @Florian Thank you for the correction. It looks like a complex sparse matrix is represented as a pair of real sparse matrices, so every real sparse matrix is exactly equivalent to a complex matrix with 0 imaginary part. `sparse(complex(full(A))) == spfun(@(x)complex(x),A)` and `sparse(complex(full(A))) == A`.

Comment: @Dmitri This works fine. Thanks! However, What should I do if I have another sparse matrix B which I want as imaginary part `A = sprand(3,3,0.5); B = sprand(3,3,0.5);
A_c = complex(A,B);` ?

Comment: @SaravanaKumar perhaps, A+B*1i would be the matrix you are asking for.